# Thymeleaf sec:authorize can you combine authorization for role OR different property?

Tags: java, spring-boot, authorization, thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf, Spring-boot, and Java. I have li items for the nav bar, and want to set access for one of the li items, so that if loggedUser.client.policyType == specific access, or they have the role of admin, the link shows so they can access the page.
I have tried th:authorize, sec:authorize, th:if.... none of it works. Any idea how to get this working?

```html
<li th:authorize="${loggedUser.client.policyType == 'Access – NO AMS'} or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" th:classappend="${currentPage == 'directBind'} ? 'active'"><a th:href="@{/directBind}"><img class="left"  height="60%" width="auto" src="/images/mail1.png"/> Direct Bind</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
<li th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ROLE_ADMIN'') or ${loggedUser.client.policyType == 'Access – NO AMS'}')}">
   <a th:href="@{/directBind}"><img class="left"  height="60%" width="auto" src="/images/mail1.png"/> Direct Bind</a>
</li >
```

You would need to add the following dependency on your `.pom` in order to use the `#authorization`. The dependency can be added with the following code.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
   <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi Alain, This code makes it so if the logged in user's policy type is Access-No AMS AND the user is an admin, to show the link. I need it to be either Or.

Comment: Ohh sorry misunderstood. The only way I know of, would be using Thymeleaf Spring Security Extras. You would need to add it to your maven though. You can see how in my edited answer.